# libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast - Running Ubuntu Docker container on Mac OS X host

Tags: docker

I'm running a GUI application in a container in privileged mode on a MAX OS X host. 
I'be been successfully able to start the GUI in the container using this link: http://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-run-a-linux-gui-application-on-osx-using-docker/

Now within my GUI application, I'm trying to pop up another window and I get the following:
Using Volk machine: avx_64_mmx_orc
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast

How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue trying to forward GUI from Ubuntu Server to my Mac.

On Ubuntu, installing the swrast driver for OpenGL rendering solved the issue -

```
sudo apt-get install -y mesa-utils libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about Mac OSX as host but I've had the same error message. Here are the two steps that worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

- install the same driver version in the container as you have it on the host

  - see: https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/issues/253#issuecomment-313995830
- re-run the docker container with the parameters `-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw --privileged` in order to make it able to use DRI

The essential part aside from the driver was actually the `--privileged` parameter.

That fixed the problem on my Ubuntu. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, sir. That solved for me. My host is a MX Linux 19 (based on Debian buster) and my container is an Ubuntu 20.04 Focal. The catch for me was to install exactly the same driver version in the container. I've had to use this [advanced search](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us).

Answer (score 2):

One of my colleagues had the same issue on Redhat 8 and solved it by installing `mesa-dri-drivers.x86_64`.

Comment: This resolves the problem for OracleLinux 9 installed in WSL2.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue after an upgrade from Ubuntu Hirsute to Kinetic Kudo but all the above methods didnt work despite the drivers being accurate.

The issue was resolved by renaming the folder /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to  /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.bak since it was containing the driver files libdrm_intel.so, libdrm_nouveau.so and other graphic driver files.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is here because they cant get flutter to work, its probably because of the snap install.

Install it manually from the tarball or clone it from github

[here's](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#install-flutter-manually) the documentation to install it manually

or look at my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74535409/20573365)