# Flutter on Fedora 36 - Linux compilation not working "unable to load driver: swrast"

Tags: linux, flutter, linux-device-driver, fedora, flutter-linux

when running `flutter run` to run on linux, a blank page appears with this in the debug console:

```bash
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_PRIVATE' not found (required by /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/../../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1) (search paths :/usr/lib/dri:/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
** (flutter_mastering:4822): WARNING **: 18:51:11.101: Failed to start Flutter renderer: Unable to create a GL context
```

searched for similar issues on the topic:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75536
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76178
- [Cannot load `swrast` and `iris` drivers in Fedora 35](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71010343/cannot-load-swrast-and-iris-drivers-in-fedora-35)
- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/libgl-error-on-fedora-28-swrast-solved-4175631923/

apparently nothing worked, here is some of my device's info:

- `5.19.6-200.fc36.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Aug 31 17:58:15 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- ❯ glxinfo | grep render

```
    GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_NV_float_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon Vega 3 Graphics (raven, LLVM 14.0.0, DRM 3.47, 5.19.6-200.fc36.x86_64)
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_INTEL_blackhole_render, GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_image, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_INTEL_blackhole_render, 
    GL_NV_compute_shader_derivatives, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_EXT_render_snorm, GL_EXT_robustness, GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control, 
    GL_INTEL_blackhole_render, GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_draw_buffers, GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,
```

- ❯ flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Fedora Linux 36 (Workstation Edition) 5.19.6-200.fc36.x86_64, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: literally no one knows about this issue but me? eh hard luck I guess I'm stuck with debugging my apps on 2 fps with an android emulator

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the snap install, what worked for me is replacing the snap version with the [manual install](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#install-flutter-manually) from github. You can also use the tarball.

```
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable
```

now to add flutter to path:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Assuming ur flutter install was at /home/user/ add this at the end of the file:

`export PATH="$PATH:/flutter/bin"`

If ur flutter install is somewhere else then change the directory accordingly

After saving and exiting, refresh ur .bashrc file with:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now check if its added to path with:

```
echo $PATH
```

If you see a /flutter/bin then ur doing fine. To check if flutter's installed:

```
flutter  --version
```

To add any missing dependencies (if ur on **Fedora**) use:

```
sudo dnf install bash curl file git unzip which xz zip mesa-libGLU clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config gtk3-devel
```

On **Ubuntu** based distros it is

```
sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev liblzma-dev
```

Comment: The error for search keywords: libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /lib64/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_PRIVATE' not found (required by /snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/../../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1) (search paths :/usr/lib/dri:/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast